# Clickhouse - Does 10 billion data need separate databases and tables

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a demand for 10 billion detailed data query. 10 billion data is stored in the `Clickhouse`. Do I need to separate databases and tables?
The table engine I use is `ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree`
The query statement is as follows：

select * from table_a where name = 'akkj';

select * from table_b where name = 'bttc';

Answer (score 1):

No, you can store any number of rows in a single table.

My production:

```
SELECT count()
FROM fact_event_shard

┌───────count()─┐
│ 1415809324034 │
└───────────────┘
```

> select * from table_a where name = 'akkj';
> select * from table_b where name = 'bttc';

Very bad idea. Clickhouse does not like such queries. You should use Cassandra, not Clichkouse.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I import 100g files and use `-- query = "insert into...`", I always find that the command is killed after a period of time. According to the log, the timeout may be 300 seconds, but I'm not sure whether this problem is caused . Have you ever encountered it? Or what is the way to import a large amount of data?

Comment: There are 300 possible reasons for this. Need to see CH logs. And size of files should not matter. Insert works in streaming manner and process by 1mil rows batches.

Comment: @datagic you could use `clickhouse-client --progress --receive_timeout=3600 --query="INSERT ... "`

Comment: @Slach OK,Thank you,I will try

Comment: @DennyCrane  My Clickhouse only has 5 billion data, but the query performance is very low, and the results can only be found in tens of seconds.My CREATE TABLE statement is
create table tablename (...) engine=ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree(...) order by (a,b,c,d,e...)    My query is `select * from table where c='ijkk'`   Is there a problem with my order by setting？

Comment: Make another stackoverflow question. I'll explain there.  But obviously you should not use Clickhouse.